# Mocking HttpContext for Web API Controllers in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, mocking, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In some of our Web API controller we call the HttpContext to look and check for the StatusCode on the Response like below. Instead of just null checking this, I figured it'd be best to mock this out.

```
Context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
```

However, all the solutions I've been able to find say to set the `ControllerContext` on the controller. When I try to do this, I don't get `ControllerContext` I just get `Context` which is read-only.

[image: Controller Context]

Is there a way to mock out the HttpContext or do I need to create a fake HttpContext for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MVC 6, you'll need to set the [`ActionContext`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/Controller.cs#L105-122) property. You can see that the [`Context`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/Controller.cs#L45-51) property pulls from there. The `ActionContext` constructor will allow you to specify your own mocked `HttpContext`.

See also:

- [`HttpContext` source](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions/HttpContext.cs)
- [`ActionContext` source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Abstractions/ActionContext.cs)

Comment: Thanks for getting me on the right track! I was able to get it working by mocking out the `HttpContext`, `RouteData`, and `ActionDescriptor` and setting the `ActionContext` to a new one with the above mocks.